# django tests folder outside app

Tags: python, django

In django i have built an app,

at the moment the file structure looks as such:

- doc

  - documention here
- app

  - tests
  - admin.py
  - ...

To match the layout the company is using for other non django projects i would like to make the structure as so:

- doc

  - documention here
- app

  - admin.py
  - ...
- tests

preferably i would like the command ./manage.py test [app] to run these tests
Can anyone give me an idea of how i could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with django-nose:

https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose